# highly resistant metal or other material in late 1700s

Tags: science-based, steampunk

What metal or material could be used to make super high-pressure canisters in the 1700s? It is for use as a fuel or propellant for a piston-driven engine to power vehicles, due to the fact that a gas canister is much lighter than the steam engine used to fill the canister.

Bonus Question:
To what level can common gasses be compressed to? e.g water vapor, hydrogen, and air (meaning the mix of gasses present in our atmosphere)

Comment: I'd go for the conservation of detail here... your readers/viewers/consumers seem unlikely to care about what a canister is made of vs what you're going to do with it. Any answer that suits your needs is likely to be grossly anachronistic or magic fantasy, so I'd quietly handwave away the materials involved, which will at least let you pretend that it is plausible ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The method used to make the air container on the [Girandoni air rifle (circa 1779)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girandoni_air_rifle) is probably going to be the best you can do.  It was hammered and riveted iron sealed by brazing, and used wetted leather to seal the gaskets.  They were surprisingly light given the era and the air pressures they could hold... that said, they were also very hard to make using the technology available, pretty fragile, and required specialized training to care for.  Iron rusts and cracks fairly easily, especially when made that thin and put under high pressure.

As for gas of choice: light gases are better gases.  Compressed Hydrogen or helium will expand faster than other gases giving you more potential energy.  Cavendish developed techniques to collect pure hydrogen in the 1700s, but high pressure hydrogen it is not exactly the safest of things to work with, and I certainly would not trust it in a Girandoni style canister. Helium was not discovered until later.

On a more important note, using these canisters for fuel will not be lighter than a steam engine because compressed air is not an efficient fuel source where total potential energy is regarded.  While it has interesting case uses (like being able to make a repeating air rifle that can fire 30 shots), the total energy behind 30 .50-cal lead shots is not really that much in the grand scheme of things when you consider the size and weight of the canister.  If you want to use this for extended purposes like for propelling a vehicle, you will not be going very far at all.

If you want to use compressed gases as a fuel source, I'd suggest using it as an actual fuel and burning it.  In this case. your best bet is probably methane. Like hydrogen, it was also discovered in the 1700s by a guy named Volta.  It is much safer to handle than hydrogen though because it only burns at specific air:fuel ratios and densities so a ruptured iron fuel bulb is less likely to blow up in your face.  At 6000psi, it has about the same potential energy density as petrol.  While your iron gas tank can't do 6000psi, you can still get pretty far off of a lower compression without overly weighing down your vehicle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_embrittlement might rule out hydrogen as a fuel anyway

Answer (score 2):

Your contention that a gas cylinder would be much lighter than a steam engine used to fill it may be in error. Some gasses at room temperature can be compressed to arbitrarily high pressure and not condense into liquids. The vessel required to contain such huge pressures might be very large indeed.

The key parameters when considering gas compression are temperature, pressure and the nature of the gas involved. Some gases like butane can be compressed and will condense into a liquid form at relatively low pressures. Hence a simple plastic containment vessel is sufficient to keep butane in a liquid state in a cigarette lighter. Should the pressure containment vessel be breached the butane liquid will rapidly boil away.

Other gases such as the so called permanent gases like hydrogen, oxygen and nitrogen will not condense into a liquid unless cooled to cryogenic temperatures. At room temperatures such gases do not exist in liquid form.

To understand the reasons for this it is important to have an understanding of [critical temperature/pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)) and [phase diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram)

Beyond the critical point gases will form a supercritical state when compressed. Such supercritical phase materials will increase in density when compressed but will not condense into a liquid or solid phases.

So to answer your question as to what extent can gases be compressed, it depends on the temperature and the nature of the gas. Many gases will not form a liquid a room temperature, meaning compression will not lead to condensation and the formation of a phase boundary. But compression would eventually produce a very compact form of the substance at huge pressures with a density somewhere between a gas and a liquid.

Gases like oxygen, hydrogen and nitrogen are examples and were not condensed into liquids until the 19th century. [Sulphur dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_low-temperature_technology#Prior_to_the_19th_century) was condensed in 1784 So might be appropriate, but in all honesty probably not.

Cryogenic gas processing was not extensively studied until the 19th century.
As an aside you might be interested in using [liquid nitrogen to power an engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_nitrogen_engine) (sadly not available before the 19th century).